# C++ detect if uninterruptible power supply is present

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, battery

I am trying to detect the presence of an UPS(Eaton)from my application in RAD Studio C++. I tried using the SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES (MSDN) but I always get the answer that the "UPS not found" even though the UPS is connected and works fine. Is there any other way to detect if the UPS is present and if it is ON?

```
int tmain()
{
SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES SysPowCap = {0};

if(!::GetPwrCapabilities(&SysPowCap))
{
    ShowMessage(GetLastError());
    return 0;
}
if(SysPowCap.UpsPresent)
    ShowMessage("UPS found");
else
    ShowMessage("UPS not found");

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Never mind the software, how do you expect this to work in hardware? If the PC isn't aware of the UPS, it's game over.

Comment: Usually the UPS has a USB or serial connection to the computer for indicating UPS and AC line status.  What is connected and are the drivers for it installed?

Comment: @stark The PC is aware of the UPS. The UPS is connected via usb and the corresponding driver is installed. I can detect the device using the System_Device_Enumerator but what I need is to detect it as an UPS and see the UPS charge level and I cannot find a working solution.

Comment: What does the documentation tell you?